# How to count words that don't have vowels?

Tags: bash, lenses

How to read a file and count the number of words that do not have any vowels?

```
clear
declare -a 
echo " Enter The String:"
read str
len=`expr $str|wc -c `
echo $len
vowel=0
for(( i=0;i<$len;i++))
do  
    echo $str[i]
    if(( str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o'|| str[i] == 'u'  ))
then
    ((vowel++))
fi
done
 echo "Number of vowels are $vowel"
```

The above is my code up to now!

Comment: This looks like homework. It also seems unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: actually this is not a homework.This is a previous question from my examination for my post graduation.Please Help me..The exam is on tomarow.Thats y am asking here.i didint get the answer from anywhere.Kindly please help me

Comment: an this has to be solved in bash shell script.Am new to shell script

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu but rather a programming question more suitable for stackoverflow.com. However. Please [edit] your question and add some example input and the desired output for that input.

Comment: If you really need to submit a solution for a `bash` task tomorrow and are still new to shell scripting the night before, then you might have started learning earlier.

Comment: wrong site - are you sure you are in the right location?

Answer (score 2):

I also believe, that this is homework... but you have to start somewhere ;-)

```
$ echo "How to count w0rds that don't have vowels?" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -vic [aeiou]
1
```

By the way, this is only one of possible million ways to do this in bash. So you can figure out the rest of them.

Comment: I think this is not the solution because OP said "count number of words NOT containing a vowel". Result should be `0` for your string.

Comment: May be Jilnesh Ajay Jîllu could post the exercise question… than it would be easier for us ;-)

Comment: Perhaps a simple `echo 0` is a good approach. I mean: how many words do you know that _don't_ have any vowel?

Comment: Depends on the language ,-) He started with `clear` followed by `declare -a`. That’s a great start for that exercise.

Comment: @PerlDuck *Psst*, getting chilly in here. *Brr*! (both words appear in `/usr/share/dict/words`). And then of course there's "sometimes Y".

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, but the OP doesn't respond to the comments and apparently is just hoping to grasp a pre-cooked solution for his task tommorow morning.  So I offered a nonsense solution for a shameless request.

Comment: @PerlDuck agreed - perhaps we should compare solutions ... tomorrow afternoon ;)

Comment: Sorry, It was too tempting a chance to resist … at least the file part is still open